# React Hook Form - Smart Components - form broken when Inputs are wrapped in an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

Following the tutorial - https://www.react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#SmartFormComponent) - works until the inputs are wrapped in an element. **What changes would one need to make to the Form component to make this work?**

```js
<Form onSubmit={(data) => setData(data)}>
    {/* wrapping the inputs breaks the form */}
    <div>
        <Input name="firstName" />
        <Input name="lastName" />
    </div>

    <button>Submit</button>
</Form>
```

---

A hacky way out of this problem would be to create something like:

```js
const InputWithDiv = props => (
  <div>
    <Input {...props} />
  </div>
)
```

*ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215997/2102042*

but this isn't a solution

---

**example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-smart-form-component-forked-8o0f9?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to use `FormContext` here. There is also this [discussion](https://spectrum.chat/react-hook-form/general/some-changes-needed-to-the-smart-component-example%7E19047ece-c24f-48b9-95cf-3230b80ec9b1) answered by the author of the library which recommends using `FormContext` for a scenario where your inputs are deeply nested. For example when using a `<fieldset />` or a fragment or as in your case a `<div />`.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Smart Form Component (forked)]

[Here](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#ConnectForm) is the relevant section from the docs.

Comment: Thanks @knoefel, this has fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I want to share my solution so that maybe it can help someone else. I followed the example from the documentation, but implemented a recursive method that iterates over all the children, and if the child has nested children, iterate them recursively.

```
export function Form({ defaultValues, children, onSubmit }: any) {
    const methods = useForm({ defaultValues });
    const { handleSubmit } = methods;

    const mapFields = (children: any): any => {
        return React.Children.map(children, child => {

            if (child.type === TextInput) { //TextInput is my custom component
                return React.createElement(child.type, {
                    ...{
                        ...child.props,
                        register: methods.register,
                        key: child.props.name
                    }
                })
            }

            else {
                return child.props.children ?
                    {
                        ...child,
                        props: {
                            ...child.props,
                            children: mapFields(child.props.children) // Call mapFields again recursively
                        }
                    } :
                    child
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            {mapFields(children)}
        </form>
    );
}
```